# Fetching data error from json format

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following JSON format

```
 Array (
    [version] => 3 
    [status] => ok 
    [response] => Array (
        [data] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [accessible_wheelchair] => 1
                [address] => 200 5th Ave
                [category_labels] => Array (
                    [0] => Array (
                        [0] => Social
                        [1] => Food and Dining
                        [2] => Restaurants
                        [3] => Italian
                    )
                    [1] => Array (
                        [0] => Social
                        [1] => Food and Dining
                        [2] => Restaurants
                        [3] => Steakhouses
                    )
                    [2] => Array (
                        [0] => Social
                        [1] => Entertainment
                        [2] => Music and Show Venues
                    )
               )
               [country] => us
           )
        )
        [included_rows] => 20
    )
)
```

I want to fetch the data from the data->[0] array.
I used the following code to insert the data into database

```
$newurl="/*the api link is here*/";
$json = file_get_contents($newurl); 
$data = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($data as $value){
        $value1=$value;//$value
        foreach($value as $newValue){
                foreach($newValue as $newValue1){
                    $name=$newValue1["name"];
                    $sql="insert into restaurant (name) values(".$name.");";
                    db_query($sql) or die("insert error");
                }
        }
    }
```

But it cannot be able to insert the data.Please whether there is any other method to fetch the my desired data and store it in database.

Comment: You have to show any messages (debug or error) that you get. Here there are many probabilities.

Comment: Do you use Drupal?! I think there is no native function in PHP called db_query! What's the database functions you are use?

Comment: you can make it a xml and then parse a xml , do here a print_r($json) so i get what you have into taht array and I'll try a code for you.For your debug doa echo $name and see if $name has a expected value before inserting it in database

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking at `$data['data']` instead of `$data` in your first `foreach()`?

Comment: sємsєм yes I am using drupal 7.

Comment: the error is `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in factual_restaurant() (line 22 of D:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\drupal\sites\all\modules\factual_api\factual_api.module).` and `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'email' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO {tbl_factual_restaurant} (name) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => Eataly ) in factual_restaurant() (line 29 of D:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\drupal\sites\all\modules\factual_api\factual_api.module).`

Comment: I dont recognise how it is saying invalid argument for foreach statement

Comment: @SubhajyotiDe check your database table `restaurant` and set the email field to be null or supply it in the `insert` query.
2- ensure that your json object is read successfully.

Comment: it cause by your column email in table tbl_factual_restaurant doesnt have default value. so you need to set default value on your table or put empty value on email column while inserted data into your table. you can pass it with change the query to: $sql="insert into restaurant (name, email) values(".$name.",'');";

Answer (score 0):

where is restaurant name?

```
<?php
$newurl="/*the api link is here*/";
$json = file_get_contents($newurl);
if ($json)         
{             
    if (!($response = json_decode(stripslashes($json), TRUE)))             
    {                 
        die("invalid json format");      
    }         
}

if (!empty($response['status']) && $response['status'] == "ok")
{   
    $data = $response['response']['data'];

    for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) 
    { 
        // in this step data 0 wich you want to extract
        /*
        [accessible_wheelchair] => 1
                [address] => 200 5th Ave
                [category_labels] => Array (
                    [0] => Array (
                        [0] => Social
                        [1] => Food and Dining
                        [2] => Restaurants
                        [3] => Italian
                    )
                    [1] => Array (
                        [0] => Social
                        [1] => Food and Dining
                        [2] => Restaurants
                        [3] => Steakhouses
                    )
                    [2] => Array (
                        [0] => Social
                        [1] => Entertainment
                        [2] => Music and Show Venues
                    )
               )
        */
    // but what i confused here is restaurant name? i don't see restaurant name here..
    }
}
```